# CSS set font-family for select options not work

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I use this code for my select box:

```
<select>
  <option>AB</option>
  <option>CD</option>
  <option>DW</option>
</select>
```

And CSS:

```
select, option {
  font: bold 22px tahoma;
}
```

Font family and weight work for select, but not work for option.

How I can set font family to OPTIONS?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. What is your issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: It works as expected. See [here](https://codepen.io/xstrafez/pen/xxZENgL) Do you have any css overriding it?

Comment: @SMAKSS option nor work for me in CHROME!

Comment: @xstrafez_ please see this image: https://pasteboard.co/JdohT9R.png . bold not work for Options

Comment: @charles no. i want style to OPTIONS. see this image: https://pasteboard.co/JdohT9R.png

Comment: We need code, not images... I've tested in both chrome and firefox

Comment: @xstrafez_ I want add style to OPTION, not SELECT.

Comment: it works for option for me.... [here](https://imgur.com/a/uLqUub7)

Comment: @NoNAME The ability to style the `option` element is very limited and support varies across browsers. A possible solution is to use other HTML elements (e.g., `input[type=radio]`) and JavaScript.